# Selecting sum of all max values per hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join, group-by

I have two tables (postgresql); one table "ls_final" containing a time series of data points for a large number of reporters. Each reporter has an id, and send aproximately 6 reports per hour:

```
id | timestamp | value
3234 | 2020-04-17 00:02:32 | 4.3421
3453 | 2020-04-17 00:02:25 | 2.7532
...
```

The reporters are of a certain type that is specified in a table "reporter_type"

```
id | reporter_type
3234 | 2
3453 | 13
...
```

I want to select the max value per hour for each reporter id of a certain reporter_type, and then get the sum of these max values, and get the count of how many reporters contributed to the sum. I.e

```
timestamp | sum_of_values | num_reporters
2020-04-17 02:00 | 7.024 | 5
2020-04-17 03:00 | 7.264 | 5
2020-04-17 04:00 | 7.711 | 5
...
```

I have searched quite a while for a solution to this, without any luck. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation. First, in a subquery, you can join the two tables, filter on the target reporter type, and get the maximum value per hour and per reporter; then, in the outer query, group by hour, sum the maximum values and count how many rows each group contains:

```
select
    timestamp_hour, 
    sum(max_value) sum_of_values,
    count(*) num_reporters
from (
    select lf.id, date_trunc('hour', lf.timestamp) timestamp_hour, max(lf.value) max_value
    from ls_final lf
    inner join reporter_type rt on rt.id = lf.id
    where rt.reporter_type = ?
    group by lf.id, date_trunc('hour', lf.timestamp)
) t
group by timestamp_hour
```